Dynamically creating rabbitMQ consumer at runtime using Cloud stream
Want to make my consumers dynamic using cloud stream. when a new consumer is needed for a new queue, is it possible to create a new consumer at runtime without changing any code base? Just changing in the application properties.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Not getting any proper documentation or resources regarding this.

Please add code as text to any post and not as an image.
